# Content Security Policy blocked a resource of less.min.js

Tags: javascript, less, content-security-policy

I'm trying to use CSP in my site, but I have three blocked errors in Console.
My style files are LESS files. In my principal style file i used

```
@import url("https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css");
```

, my only one external file.

My CSP is

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
default-src 'self';
script-src  'self';
style-src  'self' https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css;
object-src 'none';
base-uri 'self';
connect-src 'self';
font-src 'self';
frame-src 'self';
img-src 'self';
manifest-src 'self';
media-src 'self';
worker-src 'none';">
```

but my console throws this:
[image]

```
unsafe-inline
```

works, but isn't the goal of CSP. What could i do?

Comment: Open index.html (rendered) and check for any `<style></style>` This is the root issue of your problem with CSP

Comment: @Drag13 0 <style> in rendered index :/

Comment: Ok, one more try. Search for any tag that contains `style=""`

Comment: @Drag13 0 instances too

Comment: Hm. Very interesting, probably we are missing something. If you completely remove `https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css` is the error still here? Do you have any dynamic styles in the code?

Comment: yes, still here. My styles are less code: a precompiler for CSS. [link](http://lesscss.org/). I write the css, then a js Library use my code and turns into css.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219290/discussion-between-drag13-and-hawksgaze).